# How can I use Composer with no Internet access?

Tags: composer

I need to build and deploy a Drupal 8 site within an on-premise server with no internet access (developer machines have internet access, and access to a private repo).

I would like to avoid committing the whole vendor directory to the codebase, and use composer to build the site.

As far as I am aware, my options are:

1. Commit everything, including third-party modules and the vendor directory
2. Use something like [Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages.md#satis) as a local repository and mirror all the necessary dependencies in there, and reference the private Composer repository

Any recommendations on this scenario?

Comment: Interesting question, though it's not necessarily a Drupal problem. Commit everything or have a different repo for the dependencies maybe to which the dependencies could be pushed to automatically during CI build.

Answer (score 3):

I personnaly don't like to commit vendor dependencies. It makes the code review more complicated before a merge request cause the files you need to review are lost in the middle of an ocean of files you don't need to review.

In your case I would have a CI job which would be run on `release` branches and would exec `composer install` then generate a `.tar.gz` file containing all the files (including `/vendor`). That CI job would then push the `.tar.gz` on a repository manager like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/repository-pro). And finally a deploy job in `Jenkins` would get the last hosted release on the repository manager, push it to the final host, untar it and run drush commands to update the site.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a lot less work to commit everything.  If you take that approach, you're basically already done.

Mirroring the dependencies sounds like a lot of work for little gain.  If the concern is to minimize the repository size, you could make two repositories, one slimmed-down repository that just has composer and your custom code, and a second repository that includes all the builds with vendor and everything else.  For an example of this approach, see the [Terminus Build Tools plugin](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/terminus-build-tools-plugin) for Pantheon.  This example is hosting-platform specific so it can't be used as-is, but may give you some ideas.